# Unable to access shared folder using Virtualbox 6.0 (openSUSE)

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, opensuse

For my VM, I tried to set up a shared directory as follows:

[image]

However, using the terminal, I cannot seem to find the "/media/" directory under which the shared directory is supposed to be found.

[image]

I also have been unable to locate the shared directory directly:

[image]

Based on some previous answers here, I have:

Installed Extension pack for 6.0.0

[image]

Installed Guest Additions.

[image]

Edited the file /etc/group. Changed line vboxsf:x:999 and added at the end :myusername snd saved.

[image]

Restarted the VM multiple times.
Removed Guest Additions and added them again.

If you know anything that might help me, I would very much appreciate that.

Comment: I can't verify myself, but I think you have to `mount` the folder manually. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/30085093/3697870

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, until I've run the Guest Additions from the command line (`sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`). 
Then I've discovered that I was missing the following packages: `gcc make perl`.

Then I've installed them and run again the installer from command line (`sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`).

Next reboot the system.

After that the shared folders are correctly configured.